# 6-sided die roll average value

Tags: probability, self-study, central-limit-theorem

> A die is rolled 100 times. Find the probability that the mean value would
>   be between 3 and 3.5.

I've found the expected value which is 3.5 without idea what to do next.

Comment: Thanks for adding the tag; Please read the [tag wiki info](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) for that tag.  What do you know about distributions of means?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/3904/805) and [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/22532/805) and [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/49127/805); it might jog your memory. You would do better to read over your notes and text on this topic first, and then maybe [check the wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Classical_CLT) on it.  ... What can you do now?

Comment: See specifically [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/11338/805) and [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/3615/805), which nearly answer the
question for you.